# Invalid xpath expression being shown in csdef of Azure cloud service project

Tags: visual-studio, xpath, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

In the `csdef` file of Azure Cloud Service Project, I have the following environmental variable defined:

```
      <Variable name="MONITORING_DATA_DIRECTORY">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='MonitoringDataDirectory']/@path" />
      </Variable>
```

The project builds successfully. However, when I try to run the project, it throws an error saying `'/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='MonitoringDataDirectory']/@path' is an invalid xpath expression`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859313/invalid-xpath-expression-exception-due-to-presence-of-apostrophe-in-name) is a similar question on stackoverflow, but I don't know how to apply the solution to my case. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the linked question: invalid XPath there was due to a dynamic string containing `'`, something like `@name='Monitoring'DataDirectory'` if it was in your case.

Comment: `/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='MonitoringDataDirectory']/@path` is a valid XPath expression as far as I can see (it didn't get complained when I test on xpathtester.com too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem, with the exact same variable, "MONITORING_DATA_DIRECTORY".  It turns out that the error message is a bit misleading.  The XPath is perfectly valid.  The problem was that my .csdef file didn't have a LocalResource named "MonitoringDataStore" declared.  Adding this code to the .csdef solved the problem:

```
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="MonitoringDataStore" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="200000" />
</LocalResources>
```